# Change syntax color in vim?

Tags: vim, colors, syntax-highlighting

I have syntax highlighting on, but comments are set to dark blue. This hard for me to read against a black terminal. How do I change it so that the comments are colored green instead?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Probably you just need to tell vim that you have a dark background:

```
:set background=dark
```

This should change the highlighting to something better readable.

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter as I'm working with a headless server, but good to know in the future.

Comment: Put this is in command-mode on Windows, nothing changed. And I tried putting into my `_vimrc` as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is a great answer but it resets every time I quit vim.  So you should also add this line (without the ":") to `/etc/vim/vimrc`.

Comment: To make it permanent, write it to .vimrc like this: `echo ':set background=dark' >> ~/.vimrc` and also `echo 'syntax on' >> ~/.vimrc`. Comment inspired by [link](https://opensource.com/article/19/12/colors-themes-vim)

Answer (score 15):

Take a look at `syncolor.vim`. You'll find it in `/usr/share/vim/vim{version}/syntax/`.

Excerpt:

```
" There are two sets of defaults: for a dark and a light background.
if &background == "dark"
  SynColor Comment  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=Cyan ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#80a0ff guibg=NONE
  SynColor Constant term=underline cterm=NONE ctermfg=Magenta ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=#ffa0a0 guibg=NONE
  SynColor Special  term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=LightRed ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=Orange guibg=NONE
```

So the first `SynColor` line looks of interest. I confess I don't know if you can override this, as opposed to changing this file.

Comment: I think it is because it will affect all users. For this to work you need to change the light background version which could cause problems for users with a light background. It was the best answer for me however. :-)

Comment: +1 re-upvoted. If the downvote was for "all users" then that voter deserves a -1 on linux in general. `/usr/blah-anything` should immediately clue an average user that it's global.

Comment: Does anyone else think that the comment above is contradictory?

Comment: @ChrisK What is your point? ... Deducing (or not) that has effect on all users does not prevent it from having the effect. If he considers that it should be handled per user and not globally it is a perfectly valid argument. (whether or not I agree with that)

Comment: This works, but is there any way to add this to .vimrc so that it would be the proper solution? I tried but it gives me "E416: missing equal sign". I tried putting `hi` in front of it too, like other answers have it. Nothing wants to work though.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to change the color of a comment without changing the background, you can use the `highlight` command. [Vim documentation on :highlight](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight)

For example, `:hi Comment term=bold ctermfg=Cyan guifg=#80a0ff gui=bold`

Comment: This doesn't work for me for python, but it does for other files.

Answer (score 1):

[$VIMRUNTIME/colors/README.txt](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/vim-syntax-highlighting-625734/) (on my system, /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors)

Answer (score 1):

best way is to change colorscheme to another (lighter) one:

in navigation mode type:

:colorscheme <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

and then type the scheme name <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: This answer that actually adjusts the syntax highlighting rules. The accepted answer is insufficient to fix the dark comments. You must also set the colorscheme, as noted here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `colorsheme` to `desert`. Default in e.g. Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

For the googler's out there.
https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html

You can change the highlighting per syntax file, like in `javascript.vim` or `python.vim` syntax files.

For example changing a 'Comment' to be the color green. You would add this line somewhere inside of the respective syntax file.

```
hi Comment      term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermfg=GREEN ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE
```

and you can do this for others like 'String'

```
hi String       term=NONE cterm=NONE ctermfg=MAGENTA ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=NONE guibg=NONE
```